# A program With GDAL API in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, gdal

I have used gdal api in Windows but now I need use it in Linux (Ubuntu). I don't know how install the library for c++ and neither how build a gdal program with g++ or another compiler.

I saw that UbuntuGis has the library (I think). I added in the source.list file:

> deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu raring main  deb-src
>   http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu raring main

And I installed gdal-bin but I think that don't it is the library and I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using the standard features, make things simpler and just use the packaged [libgdal-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libgdal-dev):

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libgdal-dev
```

After development library installation, flags and libraries for your compiler can be found with the `gdal-config` command. For example, to compile C++ source that references GDAL to an executable `myprogram`:

```
g++ `gdal-config --cflags` `gdal-config --libs` -o myprogram myprogram.cpp
```

Sometimes simply using `-lgdal` is sufficient to find the libraries and headers.